# Como dar permissão para outros usuários uparem conteúdo no meu projeto no GitHub?

Tags: git, github, permissões

Estou fazendo um trabalho acadêmico e criei um projeto e queria que cada membro do grupo criasse uma *branch* e *upasse* parte do código usado no trabalho, porém quando alguém tenta criar uma *branch* no projeto e *upar* algum código aparece uma mensagem de erro de permissão

> Git: remote: Permission to User/algoritmos.git denied to User2

A pergunta é, como faço para permitir que outros usuários adicionem *branchs* e código no meu projeto?

Comment: "uparem"?!   "upasse"?!  "upar"??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você tem certeza que quer fazer isso? Geralmente não é adequando a não ser que projetos muito grande que precisam várias pessoas administrando (colaborando com) ele. Nos pequenos não deve ter vários administradores de repositório, caso contrário vira zona.

De qualquer forma só uma conta pode ser a dona do repositório.

Se precisa várias pessoas mexendo talvez tenha vários repositórios em um, e o mais certo deveria ser separá-los. O Github não incentiva o uso de repositório tudo-em-um.

O correto é as pessoas fazerem *pull request*, os famosos PRs. Então ela faz um *branch* e em determinado momento pede para o administrador/dono do repositório aceitar as mudanças que ele fez. Esse é o processo correto, e o Github tem as ferramentas adequadas para isso. Sugiro aprendê-las.

Mas se quiser mesmo colocar outras pessoas como administrador, o que não quer dizer que não precise fazer PR, pode seguir o que manda a [documentação](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/):

> Settings -> Colaboradors -> e ali vá no box com Add Collaborator.

[image: GitHub Settings add collaborator]

[Veja mais](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Vai ao repositório, clica em `Setting` > `Collaborator`> digita username do usuário, clica `Add Collaborator`

Answer (score 3):

Quando voce cria, lá em setting tem uma opção que voce só permite os colaboradores que adicionou.Então em collaborators tu adiciona quem pode realizar os commits e push. Deixei a imagem para melhor visualizar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]